# Performing Integration over Double Logarithmic function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have been trying to perform the following Integration:

```
 Integrate[
 Log[16* (1/b1 + 
     1/675 (25/
         2 (-161 + 9 \[Pi]^2 - 150 Log[E^EulerGamma/2]) Log[
          16* \[Mu]^2] - 
        54 (4 + 2 Log[1/2 E^(-1 + 2 EulerGamma)]) Log[
          Log[16* \[Mu]^2]]))^2], \[Mu]]
```

But the output just gives me back the integrand with the integration over mu.

Comment: Are you sure that the integral be written by standard functions ? You can still try to to it numerically, if this is acceptable.

Comment: Actually the work I am doing has limits with non-numerical values.So the application of NIntgration is in no way possible for me.

Comment: A similar question: $$\int x^x \, dx$$ and you what to a  non-numerical answer.Really ?